# error en consulta sql con is null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo esta consulta

```html
SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND role_id = ? LIMIT 0, 1
```

al ejecutar el script (PHP) me da error

```html
 "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"
```

pero si la ejecuto desde phpmyadmin si me regresa datos y si le quito el limit y ejecuto el script funciona, alguien sabe a qué se debe?

Comment: Parece estar realizando una consulta preparada, pero me gustaría saber si por medio de PDO o MySQLi, en tal caso asegurate que el marcador ? este recibiendo el valor correspondiente de forma adecuada, si el nombre de la variable es correcta o si el valor llega tal cual lo estas asignando.

Comment: si es con PDO y si llega el valor ya que si le quito la comparacion is null funciona bien solo me da error cuando agrego la condición is null

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando `OFFSET` en lugar de la `' , '` cuando utilizas `LIMIT`.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND role_id = 1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: ahora me da este error `"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OFF' at line 1"}`

Comment: la consulta quedó así `SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND role_id = 1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0`

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto, cambié esto

```html
$stmt->execute(array_values($this->bindings));
```

por esto

```html
 $i = 1;
        foreach ($this->bindings as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue($i, $value);
            $i++;
        }
 $stmt->execute();
```

y con eso funcionó.
Gracias